# Top bar inbox showing old events rather than recent post replies

Tags: bug, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

Whenever I have notifications for recent posts, such as in the screenshot below, the notifications show older events that I have seen before, rather than actual recent post responses (of which there 2 in the 30 minutes before taking this screenshot).

Expected behaviour: the top bar notification dropdown showing me the two recent responses (comment, answer) to my posts, all within the last 30 minutes and unseen.

Observed behaviour: the top bar notification dropdown showing me a suggested edit (seen and approved yesterday) and an election notification (seen and voted in 2 days ago).

This problem has existed for a while now.

[image: Inbox problem screenshot]

I suppose this post is a duplicate but I couldn't find another post describing the exact same problem.